# Long and wide table with a long sentence in a cell

Tags: tables, longtable, tabularx, tabu, sidewaystable

Hi everyone :) I'm new to the forum.

I'm trying to represent this table in LaTeX:

[image: table]

but the result is awful (as you can see the first cell in the second row is too wide and I don't know how to start a new line automatically):

[image: result]

Here is a Minimum Working Example of the code I've used:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{trig}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\begin{tabular}{lllllllllllllllllll}

\hline
& \begin{sideways}Atkinson (1998)\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}Atkinson et al. (1997)\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}Bititci et al (1997)\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}Bourne et al (2002)\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}Forza \& Salvador (2000)\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}Gates (1999)\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}Ittner et al (2003)\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}Kaplan \& Norton (1996)\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}Kerssens-van Drongelen \& Fisscher (2003)\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}Lebas (1995)\end{sideways} &  \begin{sideways}Lynch \& Cross (1990)\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}Maisel (2001)\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}McGee (1992)\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}Neely (1998)\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}Neely et al. (1995)\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}Otley (1999)\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}Rogers (1990)\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}PERCENTUALE SUL TOTALE\end{sideways} \\
\hline
Metriche di performance (multidimensionali, di efficienza/efficacia, interne/esterne, verticalmente e orizzontalmente integrate, multilivello) & & & & X & & & X & & X & & X & X & & X & X & X & X & 53\\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable} 
\end{document}
```

Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE :) // Have a look at the package documentation of makecell: https://ctan.org/pkg/makecell?lang=en, see. e.g. p. 5 ... you probably can drop most if not all of the packages you are useing right now ;-) // To find example, search for makecell (or its tag) here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/makecell .

Comment: You also can use a `tabularx` environment and make the first column have `X`  type.

Comment: Does it really make sense to rotate a table that already contains rotated column headers? Won't that lead to upside down text if the page is viewed in portrait orientation? Also, would it be an option to just show the bold text in the first column of the table and add the non bold text in a table note below the table?

Comment: Off-topic: I suggest you replace all instances of `/` ("slash") in the first column with `\slash`. That way, line breaking after the slash symbol is (re-)enabled.

Answer (score 3):

Something like the following? The solution suggested below uses a `sidewaystable` environment, employs a `tabularx` environment (with width set to `\textwidth` and the first column type set to the (slightly modified) `X` type), restricts the height of the rotated header cells, and employs the macros of the `booktabs` package -- `\toprule`, `\midrule`, `\addlinespace`, and `\bottomrule` -- to give the table a more open "look".

Note that I've also replaced all 18 [!] instances of `\begin{sideways} ... \end{sideways}` with `\rotatebox{90}{...}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{rotating,caption,booktabs,calc}
\captionsetup{skip=0.333\baselineskip}

\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}X}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}

\newcommand\mybox[1]{\parbox{\widthof{Kaplan \& Norton (1996)}}{\RaggedRight #1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\caption{Some caption}
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt} % default: 6pt

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} L *{18}{c} @{}}
\toprule
& \rotatebox{90}{Atkinson (1998)} 
& \rotatebox{90}{Atkinson et al. (1997)} 
& \rotatebox{90}{Bititci et al (1997)} 
& \rotatebox{90}{Bourne et al (2002)} 
& \rotatebox{90}{Forza \& Salvador (2000)} 
& \rotatebox{90}{Gates (1999)} 
& \rotatebox{90}{Ittner et al (2003)} 
& \rotatebox{90}{Kaplan \& Norton (1996)} 
& \rotatebox{90}{\mybox{Kerssens-van Drongelen \& Fisscher (2003)}}
& \rotatebox{90}{Lebas (1995)} 
& \rotatebox{90}{Lynch \& Cross (1990)} 
& \rotatebox{90}{Maisel (2001)} 
& \rotatebox{90}{McGee (1992)} 
& \rotatebox{90}{Neely (1998)} 
& \rotatebox{90}{Neely et al. (1995)} 
& \rotatebox{90}{Otley (1999)} 
& \rotatebox{90}{Rogers (1990)} 
& \rotatebox{90}{\mybox{\scshape Percentuale sul totale}} \\
\midrule
\textbf{Metriche di \textit{performance}} (multidimensionali, di efficienza\slash efficacia, interne\slash esterne, verticalmente e orizzontalmente integrate, multilivello) 
& & & & $\times$ & & & $\times$ & & $\times$ & & $\times$ & $\times$ & & $\times$ & $\times$ & $\times$ & $\times$ & 53\\ 
\addlinespace
\textbf{Obiettivi} (spesso riferito a obiettivi strategichi) 
 & \dots \\
\addlinespace
\textbf{Infrastruttura a supporto} (acquisizione dati, ordinamento, \dots)
 & \dots \\
\addlinespace
\dots \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{sidewaystable} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very very much! You saved me

Answer (score 2):

In addition to not rotating the entire table, using horizontal lines from the `booktabs` package and `tabularx` in order to make sure the table fits into the available space, I also suggest decreasing the font size in the header row and in the first column. I'd also move the additional text from the cells in the first column into the `tablenotes` environment from the `threeparttable` package. As an alternative, I also included a version of the table using a numberic instead of an author-year citation style.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2.5pt}
\settowidth\rotheadsize{\theadfont Kaplan \& Norton (1996)}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{caption text}
\label{key}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash\theadfont}X*{18}{c}}
\toprule
& \rothead{Atkinson (1998)} 
& \rothead{Atkinson et al. (1997)}
& \rothead{Bititci et al (1997)}
& \rothead{Bourne et al (2002)}
& \rothead{Forza \& Salvador (2000)}
& \rothead{Gates (1999)}
& \rothead{Ittner et al (2003)}
& \rothead{Kaplan \& Norton (1996)}
& \rothead{Kerssens-van Drongelen \& Fisscher (2003)}
& \rothead{Lebas (1995)}
& \rothead{Lynch \& Cross (1990)}
& \rothead{Maisel (2001)}
& \rothead{McGee (1992)}
& \rothead{Neely (1998)}
& \rothead{Neely et al. (1995)}
& \rothead{Otley (1999)}
& \rothead{Rogers (1990)}
& \rothead{PERCENTUALE SUL TOTALE}\\
\midrule
Metriche di performance\tnote{1} 
&   &   &   & X &   &   & X &   & X &   & X & X &   & X & X & X & X & 53\\  \addlinespace
Obiettivi\tnote{2} 
& X &   &   &   &   &   & X & X &   &   &   & X & X &   &   & X &   &  35\\  \addlinespace
Infrastruttura a supporto\tnote{3} 
& & & & X & & & X & & X & & X & X & & X & X & X & X & 53\\  \addlinespace
text 
& & & & X & & & X & & X & & X & X & & X & X & X & X & 53\\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\begin{tablenotes} \footnotesize
\item[1] multidimensionali, di efficienza/efficacia, interne/esterne, verticalmente e orizzontalmente integrate, multilivello
\item[2] spesso riferito a obiettivi strategichi
\item[3] acquisizione dati, ordinamento, 
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table} 


\begin{table}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2.5pt}
\settowidth\rotheadsize{\theadfont Kerssens-van Drongelen \& Fisscher (2003)}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{caption text}
\label{key}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash\theadfont}X*{18}{c}}
\toprule
& \thead{[1]} 
& \thead{[2]}
& \thead{[3]}
& \thead{[4]}
& \thead{[5]}
& \thead{[6]}
& \thead{[7]}
& \thead{[8]}
& \thead{[9]}
& \thead{[10]}
& \thead{[11]}
& \thead{[12]}
& \thead{[13]}
& \thead{[14]}
& \thead{[15]}
& \thead{[16]}
& \thead{[17]}
& \thead{\%\tnote{1}}\\
\midrule
Metriche di performance\tnote{2} 
&   &   &   & X &   &   & X &   & X &   & X & X &   & X & X & X & X & 53\\  \addlinespace
next category\tnote{3} 
& X &   &   &   &   &   & X & X &   &   &   & X & X &   &   & X &   &  35\\  \addlinespace
another category with a longer name\tnote{4} 
& & & & X & & & X & & X & & X & X & & X & X & X & X & 53\\  \addlinespace
text 
& & & & X & & & X & & X & & X & X & & X & X & X & X & 53\\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\begin{tablenotes} \footnotesize
\item{}
[1]  Atkinson (1998),
[2]  Atkinson et al. (1997),
[3]  Bititci et al (1997),
[4]  Bourne et al (2002),
[5]  Forza \& Salvador (2000),
[6]  Gates (1999),
[7]  Ittner et al (2003),
[8]  Kaplan \& Norton (1996),
[9]  Kerssens-van Drongelen \& Fisscher (2003),
[10] Lebas (1995),
[11] Lynch \& Cross (1990),
[12] Maisel (2001),
[13] McGee (1992),
[14] Neely (1998),
[15] Neely et al. (1995),
[16] Otley (1999),
[17] Rogers (1990)
\item[1] PERCENTUALE SUL TOTALE
\item[2] multidimensionali, di efficienza/efficacia, interne/esterne, verticalmente e orizzontalmente integrate, multilivello
\item[3] more explanatory text for the second category
\item[4] table note for the third category
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!